# Subversion and Ant integration

Tags: svn, version-control, ant

I'm running the following scheme: **Ant** makes java code builds and using **soscmd** API/utility it retrieves sources from a **SourceSafe** system. I know they're tightly integrated. Version of Ant I'm using is 1.6. So there's no support for Subversion for that version. My subversion server's running on a remote machine as a service and I want Ant to be able to retrieve sources using **Subversion**. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the SvnAnt task provided here - http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html

Comment: Would that be compatible with Subversion 1.7 release?

Comment: And one problem with SvnAnt is... If using native client, it won't support symbol link, because the native client doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get the svnant stuff, these details may help you the rest of the way.

What I usually do is grab the following JARs from that extraction:

1. svnant.jar
2. svnClientAdapter.jar
3. svnjavahl.jar

and add them to a folder in my project that does **not** get deployed (i.e. - they're just to be used by the build, not runtime).

Then to my ANT script I add:

```
<path id="svntask.classpath">
    <fileset dir="nonruntime_lib/svn">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

and then:

```
<!-- SVN typedef -->
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" 
    classpathref="svntask.classpath"/>
```

which then allows me to add the task call something like:

```
<!-- svn export the web root & java -->
<svn>
    <export srcUrl="http://your.svn/web" destPath="dist/web"/>
    <export srcUrl="http://your.svn/src" destPath="tmp/src"/>
</svn>
```

Not sure if you need all those JARs or not, but "they work for me." Good luck and feel free to post back with other questions/scenarios.

**Edit**

I'm not sure if this works with Subversion 1.7 (I'm running 1.6).

Okay, so this is just a partial solution. For some reason I needed to make sure SilkSVN was installed in addition to the notes above. I'm not sure why that is. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to investigate right now.

Comment: just curious but:org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml is svnant, seems like silksvn packages svnant?

Comment: great point @oers and i'm not sure what i was thinking when i wrote that. i've edited my post to reference svnant and not silksvn. thanks and great catch!

Answer (score 1):

As what the two answers below have mentioned, you can use SvnAnt; and I recommend to specify SvnKit as the svn client for your SvnAnt tasks.

SvnKit is a pure java svn client which os used by the popular gui svn client SmartSVN as the base. So if you want to write your own task, or just use some beanshell integration, you should try svnkit. It is also available for Windows, Linux, Mac OS... as long as you have JRE for it.

P.S.

I was once an SvnAnt user, but now I am using my own code to call the native svn client, because I just need to use "svn info" and "svn update".

I use exec to call the native Linux svn client to update the trunk:

```
<exec executable="svn" dir="${trunk.dir}" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="update -r ${to.rev} --username ${trunk.user} --password ${trunk.passwd} --depth infinity" />
</exec>
```

I use process builder to call "svn info" and get the actual revision number from the output (an custom ant task):

```
//java code for ant task
public void execute() throws BuildException {
    //varible verifying codes ignored......
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("svn","info");
    //The native "svn" client doesn't support symbol link, so run it in the directory instead of specifying the directory as svn info's parameter.
    pb.directory(_dirToTrunk);
    //Make sure the output is English.
    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("LANGUAGE","en_US.UTF-8:en");
    Process p = null;
    try {   
        p = pb.start();
        //then get the output and parse the svn revision number.
    }
    //catch codes ignored
}
```

Hope that will help.